# Last Non-Null Value When row not part of subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following table 'Demo'

```
Id  Value
1   Sample 1
2   Sample 2
3   NULL
4   NULL
5   NULL
6   Value 4
7   NULL
8   Value5
9   NULL
10  value6
```

defined as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Demo](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) SPARSE  NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Demo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

In this Table, the Value field (as per the business logic) is supposed to change only there is change. If the value doesn't change, it would be denoted by NULL (implying it has the last non-null value).

To retrieve the last Known Value for each null encountered, I am using the following query (inspired from the [Link](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle)).

```
  
WITH C AS
(
  SELECT id, [Value],
    MAX( CASE WHEN [Value] IS NOT NULL THEN id END )
  OVER( ORDER BY id
        ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS grp
  FROM demo
)
SELECT id, [value],
  MAX([value]) OVER( PARTITION BY grp
          ORDER BY id
          ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS LastValue
FROM C
```

This would retrieve all the values as desired.

```
id  value   LastValue
1   Sample 1    Sample 1
2   Sample 2    Sample 2
3   NULL        Sample 2
4   NULL        Sample 2
5   NULL        Sample 2
6   Value 4     Value 4
7   NULL        Value 4
8   Value5      Value5
9   NULL        Value5
10  value6      value6
```

This, as seen the screenshot, works fine as long as I am retrieving the entire table. However, it becomes a problem when I am retrieving only a subset. For example, if I need to fetch information only where **Id>2**, I would get the following result.

```
id  value   LastValue
3   NULL    NULL
4   NULL    NULL
5   NULL    NULL
6   Value 4 Value 4
7   NULL    Value 4
8   Value5  Value5
9   NULL    Value5
10  value6  value6
```

As noticed the first row (ID=3) has the value 'NULL'. However, in the database, it has a value `Sample 2` from the row (ID=2), which is not part of the query due to the condition we had added.

Could someone suggest a way such that I could still fetch the Last Non-Value value even if the subquery doesn't include the particular row (the row needn't be immediate preceeding row, it should one with last non-null value)? My expected result for the above scenario would be as following.

```
id  value   LastValue
3   NULL    Sample 2
4   NULL    Sample 2
5   NULL    Sample 2
6   Value 4 Value 4
7   NULL    Value 4
8   Value5  Value5
9   NULL    Value5
10  value6  value6
```

In the actual scenario, there could be more than one Sparse/Nullable Columns like the Value, for each of which I would need to fetch the last known value. But, for the sake of simplicity, have made the example with single column.

PS: There is however the case of first in the table being NULL. This is considered an outlier from the business logic point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a sub-query to pull the first non-null value prior to your selected range and then use it for the first `Grp` if null.

```
WITH C AS
(
    SELECT Id, [Value]
        , MAX(CASE WHEN [Value] IS NOT NULL THEN Id END) OVER (ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Grp
        -- Find the first value prior to our resultset in case we start from null
        , (SELECT TOP 1 [Value] FROM #demo D1 WHERE D1.Id < D.Id AND [Value] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY D1.Id DESC) InitialValue
    FROM #demo D
    WHERE Id > 2
)
SELECT Id, [value], Grp, InitialValue
    , CASE WHEN Grp IS NULL THEN InitialValue ELSE MAX([value]) OVER (PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) END AS LastValue
FROM C;
```

Returns:

| Id | Value | LastValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | NULL | Sample 2 |
| 4 | NULL | Sample 2 |
| 5 | NULL | Sample 2 |
| 6 | Value 4 | Value 4 |
| 7 | NULL | Value 4 |
| 8 | Value 5 | Value 5 |
| 9 | NULL | Value 5 |
| 10 | Value 6 | Value 6 |

Comment: Thank you Dale for the answer, however, like I mentioned in the OP, this is a simplified table. As mentioned in OP, in the actual scenario, there could be multiple columns and for each column the last non-null might be in a different preceeding row. Let us say we have another column `Value2`,  then how would the above query change such that I can achieve the results over multiple columns

Comment: Repeat the logic for each column.

Comment: And while its good that you've produced a simplified example, don't over-simplify, so if the real data contains multiple columns, show at least 2 in your sample.